# Strange issue with HTTPS URLs in Firefox 5

Tags: dns, https, firefox

I have a very annoying problem with Firefox 5 (Windows): whenever I open a new tab and enter an HTTPS URL (like Twitter, Google Mail, ...), the page does not load and after a while I get the standard Firefox *page not found* screen<sup>1)</sup>.

Now, when I just press the button on that screen (*Nochmal versuchen* in German, I guess it's like *try again* in English versions), the page loads normaly, just as expected. It's like every secured connection needs an extra <strike>kick in the...</strike> ... an extra *invitation*.

I tried to monitor this with Firebug, but there's no trace of any HTTP(S) request. Malware scanners don't report anything on my box.

Anyone any idea *what* could cause this problem or any idea how to find the reason?

---

Addition - Monitored the process with wireshark. I see a series of DNS request for verisign names. The DNS server sends answers back, but they seem to be ignored:

```
82  23.528183   192.168.178.31  192.168.178.1   DNS Standard query A evsecure-ocsp.verisign.com
84  23.576186   192.168.178.1   192.168.178.31  DNS Standard query response CNAME ocsp.verisign.net A 199.7.51.72
87  24.531198   192.168.178.31  192.168.178.1   DNS Standard query A evsecure-ocsp.verisign.com
91  25.530960   192.168.178.31  192.168.178.1   DNS Standard query A evsecure-ocsp.verisign.com
93  25.599791   192.168.178.1   192.168.178.31  DNS Standard query response CNAME ocsp.verisign.net A 199.7.51.72
94  27.522046   192.168.178.31  192.168.178.1   DNS Standard query A evsecure-ocsp.verisign.com
96  27.569982   192.168.178.1   192.168.178.31  DNS Standard query response CNAME ocsp.verisign.net A 199.7.55.72
100 31.524264   192.168.178.31  192.168.178.1   DNS Standard query A evsecure-ocsp.verisign.com
102 31.605979   192.168.178.1   192.168.178.31  DNS Standard query response CNAME ocsp.verisign.net A 199.7.55.72
```

The last message I see is a connection reset.

---

<sup>1)</sup>

A commenter requested the text from the status screen.

> **Fehler: Datenübertragung unterbrochen**
>
> Die Verbindung zu twitter.com wurde unterbrochen, während die Seite geladen wurde.

Comment: Can't replicate. Tried a reinstall?

Comment: Firefox doesn't *have* a "standard *page not found* screen". It does, however, have standard screens for DNS failures ("Host not found") and OCSP failures ("Certificate revocation checking failed"). Could you post the exact text displayed?

Comment: @grawity (in german language? ...) I *know* that it has no *standard* screen, just wanted to point out, that it's not some server error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is not DNS related, is is after that point probably during SSL negotiation.

SSL negotiation can fail due to a flakey connection, and if you are confident in your local network connection, I would suggest looking at whether your ISP is contributing to the problem.  Perhaps if they are using caching proxies and inadvertently interfering with the SSL connection.

Try a different method of connecting, then raise a ticket with your ISP if you are unable to reproduce with the same machine on a different network.